# saving to local storage, displaying back and able to delete from local storage-javascript

Tags: javascript

How do we display the local storage items? I was able to save the data on local storage. But when the page is reloaded, it is not displaying on the page as expected. What I want to do is everything that is add-on input text be stored in local storage and when the page is reloaded. It displays on the page.

my code is as below;

```js
// VARIABLE
var todoList = document.getElementById("todoList");
var input = document.getElementById("todo");

//EVENT LISTENERS

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {

  document.querySelector("#form").addEventListener('submit', newTodo);
  //Remove from the list
  todoList.addEventListener('click', removeTodo);
  //document
  document.addEventListener('DOMContendLoaded', localStorageOnLoad);
}

// Now, we'll set up a click event handler for the document.
// Any clicks inside the document (even on the new items created later)
// will bubble up and be intercepted by this event handler
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // Check to see if the event originated at a list item
  if (event.target.nodeName === "LI") {
    // Change that element's color by appyling a pre-made CSS class.
    event.target.classList.toggle("selected");
  }
});

//FUNCTIONS

function newTodo(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //Read the textarea value
  var todo = document.getElementById('todo').value;
  
  //create the remove button
  var removeBtn = document.createElement('a');
  removeBtn.classList = "remove";
  removeBtn.textContent = 'X';

  //create an <li> element
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = todo;
  input.value = ""; // Clear out the input
  if (todo === '') {
    alert("Please add something!")
  } else {
    document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("todo").value = "";

  //Add remove button
  li.appendChild(removeBtn);

  //Add to local storage
  addTodoLocalStorage(todo);
}

//remove todo list
function removeTodo(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('remove')) {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  }
}

function addTodoLocalStorage(todo) {
  var todos = getTodosFromStorage();

  todos.push(todo);

  //convert todo array into string
  localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));

}

function getTodosFromStorage() {
  var todos;
  var todosLS = localStorage.getItem('todos');
  //get the values, if null is returned then we create an empy array
  if (todosLS === null) {
    todos = []
  } else {
    todos = JSON.parse(todosLS);
  }
  return todos;
}

//display from local storage 
function localStorageOnLoad() {
  var todos = getTodosFromStorage();

  //looping through storage and display
  todos.forEach(function(todo) {

    //create an <li> element
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = todo;

    //Add remove button
    li.appendChild(removeBtn);
    todoList.appendChild(li);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
      <h3>What needs to be done?</h3>

      <form action="#" id="form">

        <input type="text" id="todo" class="inputBox" placeholder="Enter your new task here.."><br>


        <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
      <h2>My Todo List</h2>
      <div id="todoList" class="list"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first question - where do you include your JS code in your HTML ? (maybe show full html code including header and body bottom)

Comment: localStorage returns a string so JSON.parse probably won't work on that unless it's well-formed JSON.  You might want to use ```.split``` and a delimiter while debugging.